# How to find out why Application_End is firing on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have an MVC ASP.NET web application hosted on Azure as an App Service.
3 or 4 times a day I can see that it restarts. I am logging `System.Web.HostingEnvrionment.ShutdownReason` in `Application_End()` in global.asax and the reason comes back as "Configuration Change" which according to documentation would imply that application configuration has changed.

I have asked around our small team and nobody has changed the configuration by hand.  Scouring the code I do not see anywhere that we programatically change it.  The azure site is configured to be always on.  Memory use is not near the limit when it happens, though it seems to happen more often during higher traffic times.

Is there a way to get what specific file was changed so I can log that in `Application_End()`? Or any other ways to get more detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scott Guthrie has a blog post on how to get more [information out of the Application Shut Down events](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/433194) using reflection.  I would read his post in detail to find out more about issues.

The code snippet from Scott's page to pull more information out is the following.  You could then log it with what ever tool you are using.

```
 HttpRuntime runtime = (HttpRuntime)typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime)
                                                  .InvokeMember("_theRuntime",
                                                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                                                 | BindingFlags.Static
                                                                 | BindingFlags.GetField,
                                                                 null,
                                                                 null,
                                                                 null);

 if (runtime == null)
     return;

 string shutDownMessage = (string)runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownMessage",
                                                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                                                |BindingFlags.Instance
                                                                |BindingFlags.GetField,
                                                                         null,
                                                                         runtime,
                                                                         null);

 string shutDownStack = (string)runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownStack",
                                                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                                                | BindingFlags.Instance
                                                                | BindingFlags.GetField,
                                                                       null,
                                                                       runtime,
                                                                       null);
```

It is mentioned in the comments that you may need certain permissions on the code to be able to perform the private reflection.

Good luck and I hope this helps you get closer to solving the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely delayed response, but this looks like a solid answer, thank you.